# How to ensure/force equal distribution in a HashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap

A HashMap datastructure distributes keys among its buckets based on the Key's hashcode. Mostly if the hashing algorithm is very good all key's would be distributed among different buckets. But what if all keys return the same hashcode? The insertion / retrieval operations would be of order O(n).

If i were implementing my own HashMap how would i ( or what should i do) to ensure equal distribution among the buckets? Is there even a way?

Answer (score 1):

> But what if all keys return the same hashcode?

Then you have lost the game, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Not to worry, though, since your data structure really doesn't care – *users* of your data structure might, but they are the ones responsible for the pathological `hashCode` implementation in the first case.

Theoretically, even maliciously-chosen input values can be distributed reasonably evenly with [universal hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing), but in Java, that's really not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Run something like DES on the keys to generate the hashes. A decent encryption algorithm guarantees that the results will look random.

Comment: Generate the hashes _from what?_ In Java, the consumer of the `HashMap`, not the data structure's author, gets to pick the `hashCode()` implementation.

Comment: You can randomize the generation of hashes, but that creates a real problem in retrievals. I could create a HashMap backed by an Array of TreeMaps. That way i would be banking on the key's comparability to do the insertion / retrieval (and hopefully do all that in Log(n) ). But that's just deferring the problem to the Comparable function. Is there a mathematical function i could use instead? Or some other design pattern?

Comment: Why does it create a problem on retrieval?  The key always hashes to the same value.